# Rdp through internet, one public ip, few computers

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, ip

I need to connect to remote computers through the internet by rdp, but public ip is only one - router have it, so i can`t find computers. Question is - how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a basic home router. An alternative method would be to forward the TCP/UDP port 3389 to the internal ip address of one of the machines. Then, once RDP'd into that particular machine, you could open up a remote desktop session from that machine to another one on the internal network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different ports. RDP uses port 3389 by default, but many routers will allow you to redirect ports when setting up port forward rules. You can use this to make several machines available outside your network.

Let's say your public IP is 1.1.1.1, and you have three computers with internal IPs of 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.2 and 10.1.1.3. You can setup rules to forward traffic to 1.1.1.1:3389 to 10.1.1.1:3389, 1.1.1.1:3390 to 10.1.1.2:3389, and 1.1.1.1:3391 to 10.1.1.3:3389. Note that this means you need to give static internal IPs to computers you want to connect with.

Now, when you open your remote desktop tool, you enter the port along the with IP or domain name using the same IP:Port format from my example. If you have trouble remembering which computer is which, you can choose port numbers that are easier to remember, as long as they are higher than 1024.

Unfortunately, not every router will do port redirection like this. If your router won't do this, you may want to look into a different one. The other option you should know about is that you can RDP to a computer from within an RDP session. So you can designate one PC as the only one you can get to directly from outside your network and do a traditional forward on your router that does not do port redirection... but once you RDP to this machine from outside you can use it to then RDP to any other computer on your network that has the RDP service enabled.

Comment: This is a good solution. You just need to remember what port each individual PC is using!

Also, depending on what operating system (I'm assuming Windows)version you are using, changing the listening port for RDP might differ. Usually it involves going into the registry.

Comment: As a side effect, this puts your machines on the Internet. I would much rather buy a router that supports VPN, set up VPN + DynDNS and then VPN to the network and do RDP over VPN.

Comment: Putting the machiens on the internet is what he asked for.