Remote Desktop to multiple computers using one static IP
The router from my internet provider has a  IP address of of 204.x.x.x
204.x.x.x is NOT a static IP address
I have two Windows computers connected via ethernet to the router.
Computer A is at local IP 192.x.x.1 and is set to Port 1234 for RDP (Remote Desktop) and Computer B is at local IP 192.x.x.2 Port 5678.
I can RDP into either computer using IP 204.x.x.x:1234 or 204.x.x.x:5678 no issues.
So my question: Is there a way to use ONE Static IP (maybe set the router to the static IP?) and do the same thing, access both PC's using different port numbers?

Welcome to Superuser. This question has been asked and answered multiple times already on this site. Please review the other questions. https://superuser.com/questions/35675/remote-desktop-to-multiple-windows-machines-on-a-lan-with-dynamic-ip https://superuser.com/questions/1039080/rdp-through-internet-one-public-ip-few-computers

Also, particularly because you will probably have to pay for a static IP, and because your ISP is likely using NAT which essentially blocks you from getting into your network from outside, you should consider a hosted service such as Teamviewer, which cares very little about the nature of your home internet connection. That is suggested on the other questions too.

Yes; It's possible; But you don't have a static IP address
